# How to wrap edit text having number?

Tags: android

I m creating a settings page.In that I m having many fields,from them there is phone number field also,I want to wrap this edit text which is having phone number but it is not wrapping.I m having edit text with text they are wrapping but what is wrong in the number.

Here is my xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layoutsettings"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40sp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="10sp"
        android:text="Signin with FB" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/UserFirstName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:hint="FName"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/UserLastName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:hint="LName"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/PhoneNumber"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="PhoneNumber"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EmailAddress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="EmailAddress"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/AddressLine1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="Address Line 1"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/AddressLine2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="Address Line 2"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Locality"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:hint="Locality"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/City"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:hint="City"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/PinCode"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:hint="PinCode"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Feedback"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Feedback"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:rating="0.0"
            android:stepSize="1.0" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Please suggest me what to do to solve it.
Thanks.

Comment: Do it `wrap_content` instead `match_parent`

Answer (score 0):

change the match_parent to wrap_content

i think you can wrap it so by adding

> android:phoneNumber="true"

in your XML layout. try this .

Comment: i am sorry but almost it's IDE problem try in another project in new windows good luck

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtFamousRegion"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine|number"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:digits= "0123456789" />
```